# Submenu of a dropdown menu inside a div is not aligned after scroll

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have a scenario where I have multiple dropdown menus against each Client in a table and that table is inside a scrollable div. By default only top 3 Clients are visible. When you click on the Action button against any client, it'll give you the submenu just under the Action button.

I am in trouble if I scroll the div and then if I click the Action button against 4th ,5th or 6th Client, it leaves a gap between the Action button and the submenu.

```
        <ul class="actionMenu" id="centralObjUL" >
       <li class="actionMenuLi" id="liAction" onclick="displaySubMenu(this)" >
          <a class="actionMenuLink" onkeydown="keydown('','Link1')" onblur="liOnblur(this.parentNode)" href="javascript:void(0);">Actions&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
          <ul class="actionSubMenu" id="subMenu" style="display: none;">
             <li class="actionSubMenuLi">
                <a class="actionSubMenuLink" id="Link1"  onmousemove="fnMenuMouseMove(this)" onkeydown="keydown('Link1','Link2')" onfocus="aOnfocus(this,'subMenu')" onblur="aOnblur(this,'liAction')" href="javascript:void(0);">Client link 1</a>
             </li>
             <li class="actionSubMenuLi">
                <a class="actionSubMenuLink" id="Link2"  onmousemove="fnMenuMouseMove(this)" onkeydown="keydown('Link1','Link3')" onfocus="aOnfocus(this,'subMenu')" onblur="aOnblur(this,'liAction')" href="javascript:void(0);">Client link 2</a>
             </li>
             <li class="actionSubMenuLi">
                <a class="actionSubMenuLink" id="Link3"  onmousemove="fnMenuMouseMove(this)" onkeydown="keydown('Link2','Link4')"  onfocus="aOnfocus(this,'subMenu')" onblur="aOnblur(this,'liAction')" href="javascript:void(0);">Client link 3</a>
             </li>
             <li class="actionSubMenuLi">
                <a class="actionSubMenuLink" id="Link4"  onmousemove="fnMenuMouseMove(this)" onkeydown="keydown('Link3','PRFS')"  onfocus="aOnfocus(this,'subMenu')" onblur="aOnblur(this,'liAction')" href="javascript:void(0);">Client link 4</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the example of this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/nkumar/M3MhW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the submenu is position absolute. You need to move the submenu along with with the table element.

Here:

```
function displaySubMenu(li) {
    var objSubMenu = li.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    //This would move the submenu
    objSubMenu.style.top=li.getBoundingClientRect().top+25+"px";
    objSubMenu.style.display = (objSubMenu.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block");
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It works for IE but not for other browsers like Chrome and Safari

Comment: I just tested it on Chrome and Firefox and IE10. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes it worked in all but I got another problem with it. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781427/div-content-scrolls-on-mouse-move-on-a-dropdown-menu-only-in-chrome-safari-no